# How to gather Knockout observables to put in JSON?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I really, really don't get it anymore. I'm trying to develop an interface using Knockout, but trying to 'toJSON' it gives me headaches.

The problem is as follows:

- I have a FormViewModel. This form contains logic and meta data (observables) about the form itself.
- I have FormSection, which only has 2 observables.
- I have Deletion, also just 2 observables.

I wanna AJAX that to a PHP file receiving the JSON object, but I've got no clue how to proceed from here. I just want a number of observables, not all of them. I also wanna be able to load an initial state FROM an Ajax call (with JSON).

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
    // This only has some observables
    var FormSection = function(number)
    {
        var self = this;
        this.title = ko.observable('Section ' + number);
        this.selectedPageStyle = ko.observable();

    };

    // Only observable / computed
    var Deletion = function(page)
    {
        var self = this;
        // reference to a just deleted page, to make 'undeletion' possible
        this.page = page;
        this.pageTitle = ko.computed(function(){ return self.page.title() });

    };
```

So far so good, but I've got my ViewModel with some observables, some functionality, etc. This is what I've got so far: (I removed the body of functions for readability)

```
var FormViewModel = function(data)
{
    var self = this;

    this.pages = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.deletions = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.name  = ko.observable();
    this.description = ko.observable();
    this.availablePageStyles = ko.observableArray(['Header', 'Fields', 'Signatures']);

    this.hasPages = ko.computed(function(){}, this);

    this.numberOfPages = ko.computed(function(){}, this);

    self.selectedPage = ko.observable( );
    self.isPageSelected = function(page) {};
    self.clearPage = function(data, event) {};

    this.save = function() {
        $.ajax("x", {
            // WHAT TO DO?!
            data: { data: ko.toJSON(this)},
            type: "post",
            //success: function(result) { alert(result) },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + errorThrown)}
        });
    };

    $.getJSON("x", function(allData) {
        // How to populate back?!
    });

    this.addPage = function(data, event){}
    this.removePage = function(page){}
    this.unremovePage = function(deletion){}

};
```

I've got no idea how to proceed if I wanna save the **relevant** observables. For example: I don't need `self.selectedPage`. I use that for sorting only.

- Do I use mapping here?
- How to map the relevant observables?
- How do I put that in JSON?
- How do I 'map back' from the JSON I receive from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control what is converted to JSON when using ko.toJSON you can overload the function by doing

```
viewModel.prototype.toJSON = function(){
    var copy = this;
    delete copy.//whatever variables you don't want to return to server here
    //any other variables you want to not return
    return copy;
}
```

I put together a sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rynan/hA4Kz/.

For more information and samples see http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html

Comment: You probably don't want to be deleting fields from your view model but an actual copy of the data... you're missing that crucial part.

Comment: That's what this is doing, it is deleting fields from the copy of this which is the parameter passed to ko.toJSON(). Notice in the fiddle that the greeter variable is still displayed even though it is deleted in the ko.toJSON() function.

Comment: Use the ko.mapping.toJS(model, mappingParms) method and in the properties of the mapping parameter populate the 'ignore' property with an array of the (string) PropertyNames you wish to ignore when mapping your object back to JS.